# How do I get my netbeans drag and drop widget to know whether it is rendering inside the netbeans design view window or the running application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javabeans, designview

How do I get my netbeans drag and drop widget to know whether it is rendering inside the netbeans design view window or the running application?

I'm trying to do some custom rendering. I think it has to do with the root container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Beans.html#isDesignTime()).

Answer (score 0):

This is another method:

```
Component c = javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);
String className = c.getClass().getCanonicalName();
if (!"org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow"
    .equalsIgnoreCase(className)) {
```

Although I think the

```
 Beans.isDesignTime()
```

method is better

Answer (score 0):

Testing the

```
Beans.isDesignTime()
```

with the following example

```
package test;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.beans.Beans;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestLabel extends JLabel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2438507032083091628L;

public TestLabel() {
    super();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if (Beans.isDesignTime()) 
        this.setText("Design Time");
    else
        this.setText("Production runtime");
}
}
```

It works - that's quite incredible.